# Wiring a switch to a BlueTooth transceiver

Tags: pcb, switches, bluetooth, android

**Please note:** Because this question is concerned with integrating a BlueTooth chip to a PCB and a remote device, I do believe this is an electronics question at heart.

---

I have an experimental/hobby project where I want to use a momentary switch [like this one](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=1.30270.9012201&v=1715) to communicate to an app running on either my (Android) Samsung Galaxy as well as my iPhone 7+. Anytime the switch is pushed down, I want my app (regardless of whether its running on my iPhone or my Galaxy) to be notified and react accordingly.

**Unless anyone has any better idea**, I'm thinking about using BlueTooth for the communication link, because iPhone's have now deprecated the use of 3.5mm audio jacks, and so BlueTooth appears to be the only platform-agnostic way I can send signals from my momentary switch to my app.

So I'm looking for a BlueTooth transceiver that would fit the bill here:

- Will likely solder the switch and the BlueTooth transceiver to a PCB and power it externally (battery, not sure what the needs are there yet)
- When powered on, I need the BlueTooth chip to start attempting to connect to any other devices (such as my phone) that are listening for a similar connection
- Once a connection is made and the app (running on the phone) is listening, then when the switch is being pushed (closed), I want it to fire "a signal" to the BlueTooth transceiver/chip which would in turn then fire "a signal" on to the phone; the app would then respond accordingly

**So my question:** is there a BlueTooth chip (maybe such as [these ones](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-transceiver-ics/879?k=bluetooth%20transceiver)?) that can be integrated with a switch, and be used to scan for -- and connect to -- my phone in keeping with my needs above? Are there any "*tricks*" to configuring them or getting them to work with Android vs iOS devices?

Comment: Have you checked the links under "Related" section on the right?

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh. (+1) - the one that jumps out is [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37037/a-bluetooth-device-that-will-send-data-to-a-mobile-phone?rq=1) but I don't think my question is a dupe of it because that other solution requires the device to be on a MCU board (like a RaspberryPi, etc.). My device will consist of: a power source (battery), a momentary switch, and a BT chip, and nothing more (unless BT demands/requires there to be more).

Comment: https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/02/cheap-bluetooth-buttons-and-linux/

Comment: Thanks @BruceAbbott so is an MCU a *requirement* to run a BT transceiver? Meaning I'd **have** to put my switch and BT transceiver on a breadboard that was also connected to an MCU or something like a RaspberryPi?

Comment: "AB1126A is an optimized single-chip solution which integrates baseband and radio for wireless human input device applications especially for remote smartphone camera control." - No need for an MCU or (gasp) Rpi - just buy a Bluetooth Button, wire your switch to it, redirect Bluetooth input to your app in phone.